# Debugging Problem - I'm getting random outputs from a C++ program

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

It is a very simple code that should solve the Cut Rod Optimization Problem. Most of the time it outputs the correct output but sometimes it gives random answers. I don't know what might be causing this.

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int cutRod(int p[], int n);
int max(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    int p[n] = {1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30};
    int numOfCuts = cutRod(p, n);

    std::cout << "Cuts: " << numOfCuts << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int cutRod(int p[], int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int q = INT32_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        q = max(q, p[i] + cutRod(p, n-i-1));
    }

    return q;
}

int max(int a, int b){
    if (a >= b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else if (b > a)
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

**How to regenerate error:**

Just run the program a couple of times. Most of the times, it gives 30 as answer. Which is correct. But other times, it will give a random big number as an output.

Comment: `int n = 10; int p[n]` is not valid C++. `n` must be `const`, or just change to `int p[] = {…}`

Comment: `i <= n` in loop should probably be `i < n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        q = max(q, p[i] + cutRod(p, n-i-1));
    }
```

here you are calling p[n] which is out of index but in c++ array it still lets you access that memory block having a garbage value, so you are basically adding a garbage value with returned value of function.
in array you will have valid value upto only  0 to n - 1 for p,

I guess this is the thing that is causing the problem